# How to shift a table or picture leftwards?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I need to shift a picture and a table to the left side because half of them are outside the page. I was wondering if you could help? I tried \fbox, but it doesn't work.

[image]

```
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!10}MBE\%} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!10}C\textsubscript{v}(RMSE)}\\
  \hline
  Electricity Consumption & Gas Consumption & Electricity Consumption &Gas Consumption\\
  \hline
  4.1 & 2.25 & 14.27 & 7.81 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Calibration Results}\label{Results}
\end{table}
```

Comment: (i) your table is to wide that can be fit on page, so it on right side protrude out of it, (ii) please extend your code fragment to complete small document, which we can be tested as it is.

Comment: The LaTeX code you posted (a) does not appear to be related to the screenshot you posted and (b) does not give rise to the issue you say you wish to fix. Please clarify what's supposed to be going on.

Comment: I edited the code. I want to put the table in the center of the page. Is this problem due to the size of the table?

Comment: Your table gets cut off because it is wider than the textwidth. Although you could center it with respect to the page while letting it protrude equally into the left and right margin, the output will most likely look a lot better if you make sure your table is narrow enough to fit into the available space. You could do so by introducing linebreaks in the column headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table gets cut off because it is wider than the available textwidth.

Although you could center it with respect to the page while letting it protrude equally into the left and right margin (for example using the `changepage` package and its `adjustwidth` environment), the output will most likely look a lot better if you make sure your table is narrow enough to fit into the available space. You could do so by introducing linebreaks in the column headers, for example with the help of  `\thead` from the `makecell` package  The following MWE show a comparison of both methods:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{makecell} % provides the thead command
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\usepackage{changepage} % provides the adjustwidth environment

\usepackage{lipsum} % used for dummy text. Do not use in real document.
\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!10}MBE\%} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!10}C\textsubscript{v}(RMSE)}\\
  \hline
  \thead{Electricity\\ Consumption} & \thead{Gas\\ Consumption} & \thead{Electricity\\ Consumption} & \thead{Gas\\ Consumption}\\
  \hline
  4.1 & 2.25 & 14.27 & 7.81 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Calibration Results}\label{Results}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]



\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
 \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!10}MBE\%} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{blue!10}C\textsubscript{v}(RMSE)}\\
  \hline
  Electricity Consumption & Gas Consumption & Electricity Consumption &Gas Consumption\\
  \hline
  4.1 & 2.25 & 14.27 & 7.81 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Calibration Results}\label{Results}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks. your code solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic ...

- code fragment, which you provide in question, is not related to any of showed tables
- this fragment can be written (as MWE) also on the following ways:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
With use of \verb+\multicell+:
    \begin {table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption {Acceptable Calibration Tolerances} 
\label{mbe table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
Calibration Type    
        &   Index 
            &   Acceptable Value    \\
    \hline
Monthly &   \makecell{MBE\textsubscript{month}   \\
                      C\textsubscript{v}(RMSE\textsubscript{month})} 
            &   \makecell{\SI{\pm 5}{\%} \\ \SI{15}{\%}}      \\
    \hline
Hourly  &   \makecell{MBE\textsubscript{month} \\
                      C\textsubscript{v}(RMSE\textsubscript{month})}
            &   \makecell{\SI{\pm 10}{\%} \\ \SI{30}{\%}}    \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end {table}

With use of \verb+\multirow+:
    \begin {table}[ht]
    \centering
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption {Acceptable Calibration Tolerances}
\label{mbe table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
Calibration Type
        &   Index
            &   Acceptable Value    \\
    \hline
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Monthly} 
    &   MBE\textsubscript{month}   
        &   \SI{\pm 5}{\%}          \\
    &   C\textsubscript{v}(RMSE\textsubscript{month})
        &    \SI{15}{\%}            \\
    \hline
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Hourly}
    &   MBE\textsubscript{month}
        &   \SI{\pm 10}{\%}         \\       
    &   C\textsubscript{v}(RMSE\textsubscript{month})
        &   \SI{30}{\%}             \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end {table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
After providing a new code fragment, see if the following change in it is acceptable for you:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!10}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Consumption MBE in \%} 
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Consumption C\textsubscript{v}(RMSE)}\\
    \hline
Electricity     & Gas   & Electricity   & Gas   \\
    \hline
    4.1         & 2.25  & 14.27         & 7.81  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Calibration Results}
  \label{Results}
\end{table}
```

[image]

or as I mentioned in my comment:

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!10}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{MBE in \%}
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Consumption C\textsubscript{v}(RMSE)}\\
    \hline
\makecell{Electricity\\Consumption}
    &   \makecell{Gas\\Consumption}
        &   \makecell{Electricity\\Consumption}   
            &   \makecell{Gas\\Consumption}         \\
    \hline
    4.1         & 2.25  & 14.27         & 7.81      \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
  \caption{Calibration Results}
  \label{Results}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.It works really well